# LM2576XX Output Current

Tags: current, voltage-regulator, switching-regulator

I'm confused with the terminology that is seen in the [LM2576XX Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf):
"Specified 3-A Output Current". Does this mean that it will always drive 3A output current or does this mean that it is capable of driving a 3A load where I don't necessarily use 3A (my application only requires about 100mA max)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Specified 3-A Output Current" means it can drive max 3A load. In other words, you can power up load upto 3A current rating. If you are finding suitability of IC, find out your load requirement and if it is less than 3A, it is safe to be used (considering all other parameters are within range as per datasheet such as input voltage, VIH-VIL for logic inputs etc )